# After restarting Docker, the overleaf shows that it is under maintenance

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, overleaf

I am deploying Overleaf Community Edition on a server in the local area network.
I followed the instructions in the [quick start guide](https://github.com/overleaf/toolkit/blob/master/doc/quick-start-guide.md) to run the Docker container. Specifically, after executing bin/up, the website can be accessed and used normally.
But when I press Ctrl+C to stop the Docker container and then execute bin/start to restart the container, the website cannot be used normally.
The website is still accessible, but it shows that it is under maintenance.
[webpage shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcKd6.png)

I tried deleting the container, re executing the bin/start command, and then the website returned to normal. However, after restarting the container, the website still showed as under maintenance.
I have also reinstalled Docker, but the problem still exists.
I executed bin/locator and the output is as follows, it doesn't seem to have any errors.

```
====== Overleaf Doctor ======
- Host Information
    - Linux
    - Output of 'lsb_release -a':
            Distributor ID:     Debian
            Description:        Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
            Release:    12
            Codename:   bookworm
- Dependencies
    - bash
        - status: present
        - version info: 5.2.15(1)-release
    - docker
        - status: present
        - version info: Docker version 24.0.7, build afdd53b
    - realpath
        - status: present
        - version info: realpath (GNU coreutils) 9.1
    - perl
        - status: present
        - version info: 5.036000
    - awk
        - status: present
        - version info: GNU Awk 5.2.1, API 3.2, PMA Avon 8-g1, (GNU MPFR 4.2.0, GNU MP 6.2.1)
    - openssl
        - status: present
        - version info: OpenSSL 1.1.1t  7 Feb 2023
    - docker compose
        - status: present
        - version info: Docker Compose version v2.21.0
- Docker Daemon
    - status: up
====== Configuration ======
- config/version
    - status: present
    - version: 4.2.0
- config/overleaf.rc
    - status: present
    - values
        - SHARELATEX_DATA_PATH: data/sharelatex
        - SERVER_PRO: false
        - SHARELATEX_LISTEN_IP: 10.242.187.68
        - SHARELATEX_PORT: 80
        - MONGO_ENABLED: true
        - MONGO_IMAGE: mongo:4.4
        - MONGO_DATA_PATH: data/mongo
        - REDIS_ENABLED: true
        - REDIS_IMAGE: redis:6.2
        - REDIS_DATA_PATH: data/redis
        - NGINX_ENABLED: false
        - NGINX_CONFIG_PATH: config/nginx/nginx.conf
        - TLS_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH: config/nginx/certs/overleaf_key.pem
        - TLS_CERTIFICATE_PATH: config/nginx/certs/overleaf_certificate.pem
        - NGINX_HTTP_LISTEN_IP: 127.0.1.1
        - NGINX_HTTP_PORT: 80
        - NGINX_TLS_LISTEN_IP: 127.0.1.1
        - TLS_PORT: 443
        - GIT_BRIDGE_ENABLED: false
- config/variables.env
    - status: present
    - values
        - SHARELATEX_FILESTORE_BACKEND: fs
        - SHARELATEX_HISTORY_BACKEND: fs
====== Warnings ======
- None, all good
====== End ======
```